# Biasing a common collector

Tags: amplifier, bjt

How do I bias a common collector to secure maximum output swing WITHOUT using a resistive divider? How can I use my transistor as a voltage source with output about half my Vcc?

Comment: Resistor biasing is common, resistors are low cost and compact and the method is simple and effective. You need to have a very good reason to NOT use resistor. What is it?

When asking for what would usually be an unreasonable solution you need to give as much detail as possible or answers tend to appear unreasonable.

Comment: It was given as a challenge to us by our instructor and I couldn't find any way to solve it

Comment: Arrange that your input voltage is about Vcc/2 + 0.7V (or - Vcc/2 - 0.7V for a PNP transistor).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your instructor was remembering some of the early electronics books which showed the use of a bias battery in many circuits - perhaps even a hangover from the days of valves for biasing the grid negative.

[image]